# Exporting from Report Viewer to excel does not look good

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm using SSRS to do some reporting. Visual Studio 2015 is the tool used for the design of the reports. They are done and working fine. However I should be able to export them into pdf or Excel formats. When exporting to pdf format looks really good as expected. The issue is when exporting to excel. It does not look good. Not good at all. Basically these reports consist of a tablix control to display data pulled out from a database and  headers (columns names for the data pulled out from the database). However the headers are normal textboxes with fixed text in it identifying the columns in the database. I did it this way because sometimes I need two text boxes(stacked) with different text inside(For example: I can have one large textbox identifying a class of products and underneath 5 textboxes with the name of five different products, and the data will be the quantities of the products.)  When exporting to excel this looks really bad. The high of the columns can be different, or sometimes two products are within the same column...etc..
Any advice how can i control the rendering when exporting to excel? Any tip?

P.S. Apologies for any misunderstanding or confusion but english is not my natural language. Do not hesitate in ask if you have any doubt.

Many thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is with how Excel interprets SSRS files - and more specifically tablix.

Some rules:
1. Export to PDF unless further manipulation of the data is required.
2. If further manipulation of the data is required then export to Excel.
3. When exporting to Excel, avoid any fancy formatting in your reports (headings, logo's etc. will probably all need to be removed before the user can manipulate the data.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay in answering. The report needs further manipulation that is why exporting to Excel is needed. However I kept the headers simple and basic. What I did was: I deleted the headers built previously with textboxes and instead only used a tablix control (headers and details data). Now it is working fine. Still needs some tweakings after exporting(like expand the cells in Excel as they come collapsed) but at least respects the desire format.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer can you mark it so. Thank you.